# Constant probability density function

Tags: probability

If all events are equally likely then the probability density function is constant in each of the intervals of each event

I need an explanation for this sentence.
And what does it mean for a PDF to be constant?

Comment: "If all events are equally likely then the probability density function is constant"..... this means that p.d.f is uniform distribution(continuous or discrete).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)